# CSS3 Increment Text After Animation Complete

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-counter

I am new to CSS animations so I made this little project in which there is a box bouncing and it looks pretty real. I want the text inside the box (at the beginning it is just a 0) to increment by one every time the box bounces/the animation is complete. I tried using a counter but it keeps on resetting.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #444;
  display: flex;
  height: 330px;
  width: 100%;
}

#oboing {
  align-self: flex-end;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  width: 200px;
}

#counter::before {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
  content: counter(bounceCount);
}

#oboing {
  animation-name: oboing;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.280, 0.840, 0.420, 1);
}

@keyframes oboing {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0);
    counter-reset: bounceCount, calc(counter(bounceCount)+1)
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(1.1, .9) translateY(0)
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(.9, 1.1) translateY(-100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05, .95) translateY(0)
  }
  57% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(-7px);
  }
  64% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0);
    counter-increment: bounceCount;
  }
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(191deg, #3a22bd, #ea2b0b);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
  animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='oboing'>
    <span id='counter'>0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am open to any suggestions including CSS, HTML, Jquery, JS, etc...

I would also appreciate it if someone could also explain why their code works... Many times I see answers on this website that have only code and no explaining. Please explain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By it's definition](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-increment.asp), counter-increment is a non-[animatable](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_animatable.asp) css property - that's why you're not being successful in using it in your animation. You would have to use a javascript function to count the bounces. As the animation duration is 2 seconds, one approach would be to use a set-interval approach and increment your counter every 2 seconds.

```js
document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = 0; 
function increment() {
     var x = document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML;
     //if we declare the x value as 0, it will keep resetting, 
     //so instead, put we retrieve the initial value from the span 
     //and set the variable to that value
     x++;
     //increase by 1
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = x; //set span value
}
setInterval(increment, 2000);  //1000ms in 1 sec
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#container {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #444;
  display: flex;
  height: 330px;
  width: 100%;
}

#oboing {
  align-self: flex-end;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: black;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  width: 200px;
}

#counter {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  left: 40%;
  top: 40%;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#oboing {
  animation-name: oboing;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.280, 0.840, 0.420, 1);
}

@keyframes oboing {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(1.1, .9) translateY(0)
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(.9, 1.1) translateY(-100px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.05, .95) translateY(0)
  }
  57% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(-7px);
  }
  64% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0)
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1) translateY(0);
  }
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(191deg, #3a22bd, #ea2b0b);
  background-size: 400% 400%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
  animation: Colors 4s ease infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@-o-keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@keyframes Colors {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div id='oboing'>
    <span id='counter'>0</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this clears things up for you! :)

Comment: Yep! Thanks! What would I do if I wanted there to be a new bouncing box every time the original bounced? And they should overlap and be in random x positions. Thanks! (Is this even possible?)

Comment: Ok! Thanks! I will make another question later. If I send a link, could you answer, or try? Thanks again!

Comment: @admin when you ask another question I'll be able to see the link by clicking on your profile. (I just clicked into your profile and saw that you have still only one question, so I know as yet you haven't asked another.... but I'll look out for it! :)